# React-Router v4 shared layout re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I know that this question has been asked before, but I keep having issues with this.

The issue I have is that when I use a *Page Layout*-like component to wrap my routes, this page layout is **re-rendered** when changing path.

In react-router v3 I did something like this:

```
<Router history={this.props.history}>
  <Route path="/">
    <IndexRedirect to="/Dossiers" />
    <Route path="/Dossiers" component={MainLayout}>
      <IndexRoute component={DossiersPage} />
      <Route path="/Dossiers/:dossierId/:title" component={DossierDetailsPage} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

When moving paths, this would NOT re-render the `MainLayout` component (which is easily checked by putting something in state inside `MainLayout`).

Now, in react-router **v4** I tried a couple of approaches already:

- Wrapping `Switch` with the `MainLayout` component
- Creating a `RouteWithMainLayout` component which wraps `Route` (as described here: https://simonsmith.io/reusing-layouts-in-react-router-4/)
- Some of the approaches described here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3928

However, all solutions I've tried seem to re-render the `MainLayout` component, basically causing `state` to reset to its initial value(s).

---

**tldr;** How do I create a *wrapping component* in `react-router v4` which doesn't re-render when changing paths

Answer (score 3):

I put together a codesandbox example of how I'm using a "page layout" type of component. It uses React Router v4.1.2.

https://codesandbox.io/s/Vmpy1RzE1

As you described in your question, and as was described in Matt's answer, the `MainLayout` component wraps the routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <MainLayout>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </MainLayout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

It is true that the `MainLayout` component re-renders when I navigate the app, in the sense that `render` is called by React. But, the `MainLayout` component is never unmounted, so the state never re-initializes.

I've placed some `console.log`s around my example to show this. My `MainLayout` looks like this:

```
export default class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  state = {
    layoutCreatedOn: Date(),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //This will not fire when we navigate the app.
    console.log('layout did mount.');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    //This won't fire,
    // because our "shared page layout" doesn't unmount.
    console.log('layout will unmount');
  }

  render() {
    //This does fire every time we navigate the app.
    // But it does not re-initialize the state.
    console.log('layout was rendered');

    return (
      <div styles={styles}>
        <h5>
          Layout created: {this.state.layoutCreatedOn}
        </h5>
        <Sidebar />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you click around the app, you'll see a few things.

1. `componentDidMount` fires only once.
2. `componentWillUnmount` never fires.
3. `render` fires every time you navigate.
4. Despite this, my `layoutCreatedOn` property shows the same time as I navigate the app. The state is initialized when the page loads, and never re-initialized.

Comment: This makes layout for all your Routes. How can you create a layout only for specific routes?

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need `IndexRedirect`, instead just wrap all of your routes in your `MainLayout` component, such as:

```
<Router history={this.props.history}>
  <Switch>
    <MainLayout>
      <Route path="/" component={DossiersPage}/>
      <Route path="/Dossiers/:dossierId/:title" component={DossierDetailsPage} />
    </MainLayout>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Using this re-renders the MainLayout component

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct solution for React Router v4 as stated [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3928#issuecomment-282497870)

So basically you need to use the render method to render the layout and wrap your component like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN} render={props => 
      <LoginLayout {...props}>
        <Login {...props} />
      </LoginLayout>
    } />
    <Route path={ROUTES.REGISTER} render={props => 
      <LoginLayout {...props}>
        <Register {...props} />
      </LoginLayout>
    } />

    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

This will not cause re-rendering of the layout when you are changing the routes.

When you have many different components with many different layouts you can go ahead and define them in a route config array like the example from the [issue I linked](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3928#issuecomment-282497870):

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home
  },
  { path: '/about',
    component: About,
  },
  { path: '/cart',
    component: Three,
  }
]

<Router>
  <Switch>
    {routes.map({ path, exact, component: Comp } => (
      <Route path={path} exact={exact} render={(props) => (
        <LayoutWithSidebarAndHeader {...props}>
          <Comp {...props}/>
        </LayoutWithSidebarAndHeader>
      )}/>
    ))}
    <Route component={Error404}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```